# r import excel sheets from file if sheet contain specific value in specific column

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

I am importing into r multiple similarly structured sheets from a single excel file but would like to know how to adapt below to only import those sheets that contain (among other values) a certain value in a specific column (column = sport, value = football)

```
excel_sheets("mydata") %>%
  map_df(~read_xlsx("mydata", .x)
```

Is it possible to adapt my code to do this?

Comment: How do you expect R to "know" if the `sport` column contains the value `foortball` without reading the sheet?  Telepathy?  ESP?  You're better off reading in all the sheets and then discarding the ones you don't want.  Unless there's another way of signalling that the sheet is relevant.  Its name, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will include the sheet if `sport` column has at least one value of `'football'`.

```
library(readxl)
library(purrr)

excel_sheets("mydata") %>%
  map_df(~{
    tmp <- read_xlsx("mydata", .x)
    if(any(tmp$sport %in% 'football')) tmp
    })
```

Comment: OP wants to import *only* those sheets containing `football` in the `sport` column, not import all and then discard those that don't.  However, I agree your solution is an example of the only sensible approach.